# A question regarding the vector bundle associated to the frame bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $E\to M$ be a smooth real vector bundle of rank $n$ and $\mathcal{F}E\to M$ be the associated frame bundle. The frame bundle is a principal $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$-bundle and $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ has a natural action on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus we can construct the associated vector bundle $\mathcal{F}E \times_{GL(n,\mathbb{R})} \mathbb{R}^n \to M$. This is again a vector bundle of rank $n$. A natural question is that :

> Is there a relation between the two bundles $\mathcal{F}E \times_{GL(n,\mathbb{R})} \mathbb{R}^n \to M$ and $E \to M$ ?

I guess that they would be isomorphic, but I am unable to see if there is a natural isomorphism between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that they are isomorphic. The natural isomorphism to take is $\mathcal{F}E \times_{\text{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})} \mathbb{R}^n \to E$ given by

$$[\xi, v] \mapsto \xi(v)$$

(Here I am thinking of $\xi$ as an isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a fiber of $E$). Once you see that this is well-defined (exercise), it is clearly an isomorphism, since it covers the identity and on each fiber it's given by an isomorphism $\xi$.

This observation tells you that the construction which associates to a vector bundle its frame bundle gives an equivalence between vector bundles of rank $n$ and principal $\text{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$-bundles, which is a neat and useful fact.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks. Now I understand, the key was to look at $\xi$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a fibre of $E$.
To arrive at the conclusion of the last para, we would have to prove that every principal $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$-principal bundle is the frame bundle of some vector bundle (upto isomorphism). To do this we could simply pass to the associated vector bundle.
By the way, another way of seeing this is to observe that both vector bundles and GL(n,R)-bundles are given by transition functions satisfying the cocycle conditions. That is how Husemoller proves it in his book.

Comment: @Pedro, I don't understand your explanation for this map being an isomorphism. Are you saying: for $v\in E_x$ there is some frame $\xi$ such that $\xi(e_1)=v$, then $[\xi,e_1]\mapsto v$?